# Как сделать scale анимацию Relativelayout

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Есть `RelativeLayout` с вложеным в него `TextView`

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout_examples_case"
            android:gravity="center"

            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="95dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:text="assess performance"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textSize="@dimen/main_word_font_size"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Если я делаю такую анимацию

```
 ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "scaleY", 0.5);
```

в таком случае изменяеться размер RelativeLayout и вмести с ним сплюскиваеться `TextView` меня интересует можно ли сделать такую анимацию контейнера не затрагивая вложенные в него элементы? Ну... помимо того что бы скалить вложенные элементы...